# Importing custom modules in schedulling AWS Sagemaker Pipelines

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-event-bridge, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I understand that AWS Sagemaker Pipelines can be run on a scheduler using EventBridge. However, I will like to check if AWS Sagemaker Pipelines allows the user to import custom modules inside the code? All the examples that I had found online all seem to just run a jupyter notebook without importing any other custom scripts.

I have a jupyter notebook **main.ipynb** that is calling another custom script **utilities.py** in the code

```
from utilities import *
```

I have tried **scheduling a notebook job** in Sagemaker Studio but it seems that only the **main.ipynb** is being imported into another virtual machine for running as I could not find the **utilities.py** script anywhere.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.. If you need `utilities` in a notebook job, consider storing it on S3 and download the script in your notebook. Pipelines are an orchestration tool, and currently don't support running a notebook. If you're running a script, then you can use training jobs and use a source folder (your home folder) for the training job with the utilities.